# ssrs : fix of numbers of boxes for each page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a report , which do what it is supposed to do (or almost)

One thing that still bugs me is the following

On some pages , I have 4 boxes (see below)

[image]

On other pages, I have 5 boxes (see below).

[image]

The number of boxes can change depending on unknown variables/factors.

I would like to have 5 boxes in every page. I'm not sure how to do that. I checked on google and all that came up was some trick to have a fixed number of rows, which is not what I'm looking for

[http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/11/displaying-fixed-number-of-rows-per-ssrs-report-page.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRSOl.png)

Thanks for any insights you will be able to provide me , with.

Comment: Are you showing a header on the first page that gives the content less room?

Comment: Hi @cᴏʀʏ , no header in the first page , just a cover page with a page break. The issue happens sometimes with 2 pages in a row in the middle of the report and sometimes for 3 pages. It is ... random

Comment: My suggestion would be to tighten up the white space around your labels to shrink the height of each row just a little bit. Chances are you are getting very close to tipping point of pushing the fifth row onto the next page, so if you give the rows some wiggle room they might all fit.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ issue is I don't have whitespace ... Each of my rows have a height of `0.6` mm , which is already tight (at least for me).  I do not wish to make it tighter. Who knows what kind of weird behavior I will trigger if I squeeze the space even more ...

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I had a look at the printed version of my report. What you said does not fit my case. Some boxes are heavily loaded with text (close the 140 characters string in some case and for some rows) and yet there are 5 boxes. On pages with only 4 boxes, the characters string do not have that many characters (less than a hundred) yet there are only 4 boxes ...

Comment: Unfortunately without having the .rdl file and some sample data it would be hard to further advise you. Hopefully someone with a similar experience will see this and chime in.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Can I send you something (through pastebin or else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fixed number of rows solution](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/11/displaying-fixed-number-of-rows-per-ssrs-report-page.html) that you linked to in your question is actually partially what you want. Your "boxes" are presumably repeating based on rows in a dataset, what you are asking to do is ensure that *exactly* five rows appear on each page. The linked solution uses an extra parent RowGroup to force a page break after *n* rows, which will ensure there are not **more** than *n* rows per page.

However the issue you are seeing is that sometimes there are four rows per page and this will be because the combined content of the rows ("boxes") is larger than a single page and therefore when the report is rendered the rendering engine is forced to split it onto a new page. The only way to avoid this is to either ensure that five rows of content is never larger than a page (e.g. by shrinking fonts or changing layout and/or setting the CanGrow property to False on relevant report items), or by mandating a lower number of rows per page (e.g. 4 or 3) when setting up the parent row group that forces the page breaks.

Comment: Hi @Nathan , I will have a look at the last option you proposed

Comment: absolutely brilliant! The `CanGrow` option did the trick! Many thanks for your help